# How can I avoid adding empty line to the end of RichTextbox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
foreach (string link in links)
{
    rtbPaths.AppendText(link + Environment.NewLine);
}
foreach (string link in links1)
{
    rtbPaths.AppendText(link + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

The problem is when the second foreach finishes there is an empty line at the bottom of the RichTextbox. How can I make that it will not add the empty line at the end?

Comment: How can i also make that when i'm running the program the scroller in the richTextbox will be at the top on the first line and not at the bottom ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rtbPaths.AppendText(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, links));
rtbPaths.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
rtbPaths.AppendText(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, links1));
```

or just

```
rtbPaths.AppendText(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, links.Concat(links1)));
```